# TFS 2010 - Making fields required

Tags: tfs, comments, required

I'm a first time user of this site. Apologies in advance if I hadn't searched well enough for my question.

I'm looking at tweaking TFS 2010's bug creation abilities slightly. I'd like to force the 'Comment' field linked to the History. Basically, after someone makes a series of changes, I want to force that person to enter some details before committing the changes.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Use "TFS Power Tools" -- you can change field properties, add new fields, change the process workflow, etc. Download and Install it for free -- very easy to use, tutorials are available too.

Answer (score 0):

You must right click on your team project, choose "Team Project settings" and then "Source Control". This launches the "Source Control Settings" window with three tabs.

```
1. Check out Parameters

2. Check in policy <- your target (Select “Changeset Comments Policy”)

3. Check in Note
```

when you select your rule, you click OK et you can test

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however, is this for configuring the 'Bug' type? I wish I could add a screenshot to show you wht I mean.

Comment: This is for requiring checkin comments, not work item comments.

Comment: Happy to help you user1504409